# Why Can you return a function by reference for a local variable and not for temporary variable? c++

Tags: c++, reference, temporary

for example this function f defined like this :

```
int f(int x){return x;}
```

as you know You cant assign a reference to this temporary int :

```
int& rf=f(2);// this will give an error
```

but if I redefined my function f like this:

```
int& f(int x){return x;}
f(2);// so now f(2) is a reference of x, which has been destroyed
```

so my question is : how can the compiler not let you create a reference to a temporary which will be destroyed after the statment (int the 1st case). and on the other hand it lets you create a reference f(2) to `x` while compiler knows that this one will be destroyed after `return`.

Comment: This is UB (well, accessing the reference, anyway) and any sane compiler will warn you about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Returning a reference to a local is something that can be difficult or impossible for the compiler to detect. For example:

```
int & f()
{
    int x;
    extern int & g(int & x);

    // Does this return a reference to "x"?
    // The compiler has no way to tell.
    return g(x);
}
```

Even without calling external functions, it can still be difficult to analyse a complex program flow to tell whether the returned reference is to a local; rather than trying to define what counts as "simple enough" to diagnose, the standard doesn't require a diagnostic - it just states that it gives undefined behaviour. A good compiler should give a warning, at least in simple cases.

Binding a temporary to a non-const reference is something that the compiler can easily detect, and so the standard does require a diagnostic for that.

Answer (score 1):

Because, as specified by the standard, returning a reference to a temporary variable from a function is undefined behavior.

What's wrong is actually the function definition:

```
int& f(int x)
{
   return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind temporary rvalue to a const reference to prolong it's lifetime.

```
const int& rf=f(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

To reject your first code snippet, the compiler applies the simple rule that you cannot directly bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

To reject the second, the compiler could perhaps apply a rule that the `return` statement of a function that returns by reference cannot be the name of an automatic variable (including a by-value function parameter). That seems to me a fairly easy rule too.

I don't know why the standard doesn't specify that doing so is ill-formed. I can't think of any valid use for it, but perhaps at the time of the first standard it would have created an excessive burden on some implementation or other. Or perhaps it was felt that it's only half a fix and not worth bothering with (there are plenty of other ways to create a dangling reference, this just blocks one of them).

The reason why the standard does not in general stop you creating a non-const reference bound to a temporary is that there are occasions when it's OK. For example:

```
struct Foo {
    static void set(Foo &f) { f.val = 0; }
    int val;
    int bar() {
        set(*this);
        return val;
    }
};

std::cout << Foo().bar() << "\n";
```

Here `Foo()` is a temporary, and the line `set(*this)` binds it to a non-const reference (but not directly, it uses an lvalue expression `*this` that refers to a temporary some times but not others). There's no problem here, the temporary outlives the reference. So it would be unnecessarily restrictive for the language to somehow prevent any temporary from ever being bound to any non-const reference.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a good idea to return by reference unless you're sure the reference you're returning will still be pointing at something valid.

otherwise, undefined behavior is expected.

since the variable is local, you can be sure that teh reference is invalid

Comment: Since the variable is local, you can be sure it's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that semantically there is no difference between a variable on a stack, or a variable on the heap etc. - So the language has no choice but to allow this, even if it is undefined behavior.
In the first example you get an easy compile error, because you're trying to bind a reference on a temporary variable, which can be forbidden by the language.

Comment: yes I understand that but why it work for the second example ? and why you mentioned the heap, and i did not say anything about the heap

Comment: @AbdessamadBond There is the answer why your second example doesn't work.. and I mentioned the heap, because returning a reference to a variable on the heap is ok (even if it is probably bad style). Semantically there is no difference between a variable on the heap and one on the stack, while there is a difference between a variable and a temporary value.